# Derivative of a Rotation Matrix with changing rotation axis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, robotics

Just to introduce the background of this question: As many of you know a Rotation Matrix can transform a point $^{B}\textrm{p}$ described in a rotated Coordinate Frame {B} into the point $^{A}\textrm{p}$ described in the Coordinate Frame {A} by:

$^{A}\textrm{p}$=$^{A}\textrm{R}_B \ ^{B}\textrm{p}$

The Rotation Matrix's $^{A}\textrm{R}_B$ columns are the unit vectors of {B}'s axis described in Frame {A}.

Also the Rotation about a given axis can be given by:
$^{A}\textrm{R}_B$=$e^{[\hat{w}]_x\theta}$ , whereas $[\hat{w}]_x$ is the skew-symmetric 3x3 matrix of the unit vector of $\hat{w}$ (deschribed in Frame A), around which the Frame is being rotated. $\theta$ is the rotation angle (and a scalar).

Now my question:
Almost every book and paper i found states that the time-derivative of the Rotation Matrix is the following:

$\frac{d}{dt}(^{A}\textrm{R}_B)$= $[w]_x \  ^{A}\textrm{R}_B \qquad (1)$

Does the solution require that the direction of $\hat{w}$ remains constant at all times?

Because if we use the chain rule on with a (1):

$\frac{d}{dt}e^{[\hat{w}]_x\theta}$ = $\frac{d}{dt}([\hat{w}(t)]_x\theta(t)) \cdot e^{[\hat{w}]_x\theta}$ = $\frac{d}{dt}([\hat{w}(t)]_x)\theta(t) e^{[\hat{w}(t)]_x\theta(t)} + [\hat{w}(t)]_x)\dot{\theta}(t) e^{[\hat{w}(t)]_x\theta(t)}$

which can be further simplified to:

$\frac{d}{dt}e^{[\hat{w}]_x\theta}$ = $(\frac{d}{dt}([\hat{w}(t)]_x)\theta(t)  + [w(t)]_x)^{A}\textrm{R}_B$

Whereas $[w(t)]_x=[\hat{w}(t)]_x\theta(t)$

Thus this is not equal to (1) and an addition term is generated.

So which of these equations is true now, when the rotation is not being done around a constant axis? Or did i do something wrong?

Greetings,

1lc

Comment: I just noticed that the time-derivative of a time-dependent matrix exponential is not trivial: $e^{A(t)} \neq A(t) e^{A(t)}$. So my solution is wrong. But the Solution in (1) isnt it either. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noticed in your comment, the time (single-parameter) [derivative of the matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential#The_exponential_map) doesn't have a nice form analogous to the scalar exponential.

Your Equation 1 is essentially the *definition* of the "angular velocity" vector $\omega$. An orthogonal time-varying matrix $R(t)$ always satisfies,
$$
R R^T = \mathbf{1} \ \ \ \ \forall t
$$$$
\implies\ \ \dot{R} R^T + R \dot{R}^T = \mathbf{0}\ \ \ \ \forall t
$$

We define the following also time-varying matrix,
$$
\Omega := \dot{R} R^T\ \ \ \ \forall t
$$

and note that, from the above, it is always skew-symmetric,
$$
\dot{R} R^T = -R \dot{R}^T\ \ \implies\ \ \Omega = -\Omega^T\ \ \ \ \forall t
$$

Thus $\Omega$ can be treated as the [cross-product linear operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Conversion_to_matrix_multiplication) form of some time-varying vector $\omega(t)$. By simple rearrangement of the $\Omega$ definition, we have your Equation 1,
\begin{equation}
\dot{R} = [\omega]^{\times} R\ \ \ \ \forall t
\end{equation}

If $R$ rotates some $B$-coordinates to $A$-coordinates then we call $\omega$ the angular velocity expressed in $A$-coordinates.

In conclusion, your Equation 1 holds even for time-varying $\omega$, essentially by definition.

It is a linear time-varying matrix ODE, but don't take the "matrix" part lightly. The *solution* is [non-trivial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral) unless the direction of $\omega$ is constant. This is due to the lack of commutivity of the Lie group $\mathbb{SO}$. Hopefully that clears things up!

Comment: I understand the math you did there, but because I'm the type of guy to question everything i wrote a Matlab Script and approximated the time-derivate and compared it with the solution that Equation (1) produces. It shows that for a constant (non tumbling w-vector) the Solutions are essentially the same for small timesteps. But when i chose a tumbling w-vector (for example here w rotates around the z-axis in the XY-Plane) the solutions differ quite a bit.

Comment: [Matlab-Code](https://justpaste.it/6u91i) <-- Link to Matlab Code, the skew function generates a skew-symmetric matrix out of a vector.

Comment: @1lc The subtraction operation you used in your finite-difference is not defined for the group of rotation matrices. You may be interested in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1119) for more insight.

Comment: Now I am confused. The book i am Reading (Robotics Vision and Control by Peter Corke) states that the derivative can be approximated by a finite difference. I thought that this is true because it makes sense and it also works in my Matlab Script for the constant w-vector. 
Here is the link to the page i am referring to:


[Book-Page](https://i.imgur.com/kOUCJI0.jpg) <- Link to Book-Page

Comment: @1lc In the limit, the finite-difference will match the exact derivative like your book says, but it will require a much smaller timestep than a "boxminus"-based approximation of the derivative (see the paper I linked). In robotics, it is *rare* now to see people using vector operations on $\mathbb{SO}3$ and then reprojecting. I suspect your book will explain the modern Lie algebraic approach later.

Comment: @1lc I actually examined your code closely now. The timestep seems pretty small, so I don't think that is the problem (though my statement about avoiding vector subtraction of group members still holds). The problem with your code is where you write `theta=w*t`. That is erroneous if `w` is changing direction. What even is `theta`? An angle about what? The line `theta=w*t` is what integrating a rotation about a *fixed* axis would yield. You cannot integrate your Equation 1 that easily if the axis is changing.